# Including external libraries jar into NetBeans Project without moving problems

Tags: java, netbeans, libraries

Problem: How to include extenal libraris and how to store in the files project in order to don't have problems when you move the project folder or something like that.

I am thinking about CVS project. If I include a jar (that its stored in project folder), and other user go on working, he has problems with referencing libraries...

How to include libraries?
How to store libraries?

What is the proper way to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using Maven and listing the libraries as dependencies is usually a great way to avoid the problems you describe. Is using Maven an option for you?

Comment: @bruno-lowagie yes, could be. But, can I set as dependencies all the libraries I need? How can I know that? Can I simply set the name of libraries as dependencies?

Comment: It's easier to show you a video than to explain it in text: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VcOi99zW7O4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to make sure that everyone has the libraries that are needed, is to use Maven. I've made a video [How to import iText 7 in Netbeans to create a Hello World PDF?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VcOi99zW7O4)  that shows how to create a Maven project in NetBeans.

NetBeans creates a `pom.xml` file to which you can add dependencies. For instance;

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>io</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.18</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When you build the project, these libraries will be downloaded from the Maven [Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/). Obviously, I assume that you are using library that are published on that repository. If not, you have to create your own repository. For instance: at iText, we have a couple of private repositories for our own use within the company.